# Binary to denary conversion

Tags: c#, binary

I can't figure out why my binary to denary number converter doesn't work. I need a simple solution to demonstrate to GCSE Computer Science students. please help:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string binaryNumber;
    int[] placeValues = { 128, 64, 32, 16, 8, 4, 2, 1 }; 
    // Array stores place values of the digits
    int denaryNumber = 0;

    Console.WriteLine("Please enter an 8-bit binary number: ");
    binaryNumber = Console.ReadLine();

    // The digits will now be multiplied by the place values
    for (int index = 0; index < binaryNumber.Length; index++)
    {
        denaryNumber = denaryNumber + 
        (Convert.ToInt32(binaryNumber[index]) * placeValues[index]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("\n" + binaryNumber + " = " + denaryNumber);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: What does "doesn´t work mean"? Any exception? Unexpected results?

Comment: Rather than convert & multiply you could just check each digit & add if it is '1' _"if (binaryNumber[index] == '1') denaryNumber += placeValues[index];"_

Comment: Thank you! That worked a treat!

Answer (score 0):

When working with *strings* like

```
 "011001"
```

you should subtract `'0'` to get *integer* digit: `1 == '1' - '0'`, while `Convert.ToInt32('1') != 1`, i.e.

```
binaryNumber = Console
  .ReadLine()
  .Trim()                            // Let's be nice and remove (white) spaces 
  .PadLeft(placeValues.Length, '0'); // What if "011" is the input?

for (int index = 0; index < binaryNumber.Length; index++)
{
    denaryNumber += (binaryNumber[index] - '0') * placeValues[index];
}
```

Be careful with *indexes*: you should have `binaryNumber` being exactly the *same length* as `placeValues` (the very reason I've added `PadLeft`).

**Edit**: In real life we do conversion as simple as

```
int denaryNumber = Convert.ToInt32(binaryNumber, 2);
```

Comment: @bommelding: Quite right, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
Convert.ToInt32(binaryNumber[index])
```

does not do what you want. It gives you the internal representation (ASCII value) of the character, not the numerical value represented by it. Use

```
(int)Char.GetNumericValue(binaryNumber[index])
```

instead. Alternatively, you could subtract `'0'`

```
binaryNumber[index] - '0'
```